# Неубираемая тень в форме (Bootstrap)

Tags: css, bootstrap

Подскажите, пожалуйста - как убрать данную тень из form-control. 
[image: Вид тени]

Я уже пытался делать это через :

```
-moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline:none;
```

Но по какой-то причине не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не тень а стандартное оформление браузера (стандартная рамка).
Нужно дописать `border: 0;`

Comment: Верно, спасибо! Я так и думал, только писал border : none, что также не помогало.